# How To Fade Still Image In VSE From B/W To Color?

Tags: edit-mode

I'm using vers 2.83, and would like to "fade" a still image, from black/white to full color in VSE.  I've made multiple attempts at inserting keyframes to the Color/Saturation in VSE, but it seems to only allow either B/W OR color, but cannot "fade" from one to the other.

Need help, please!

Comment: Try to duplicate the image, make BW one of them and add a cross fade between them.

Comment: FFeller - Worked, and accomplishes the needed effect!  Thanks.  Still wonder why animating the Color/Saturation doesn't work??  Oh well, thanks again for the suggestion!